# Selection of the maximum value from duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure:

[image]

There are records in the table that can be duplicated by the code field.
Also, these records have a column deleted_date, which determines the time of the deleted record.
I create a query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM analyzes 
WHERE code IN (
    SELECT code 
    FROM analyzes 
    WHERE deleted = 1 
    GROUP BY code 
    HAVING count(code)>1
)
```

But it does not work correctly.
Prompt please, at whom it is a lot of experience in sql, whether probably by means of sql to make the given request?

Comment: What type of SQL? And version?

Comment: type of sql - mysql | 5.7.9

Comment: "it does not work correctly" is not a problem description... Why not? What did it do? Why was that wrong? What should it do instead? And your sample data should be posted as aligned text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery return ony code which is not sufficient to identify the correct row in outer query, you also need the correct deleteddate you identified as maximum. This is based on join:

```
SELECT id 
FROM analyzes a1, (SELECT code, max(deleted_date) as dd
    FROM analyzes 
    WHERE deleted = 1 
    GROUP BY code 
    HAVING count(code)>1) a2
where a1.code = a2.code and a1.deleted_date = dd and a1.deleted = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` with `not exists` :

```
select a.*
from analyzes a
where not exists (select 1 from analyzes a1 where a1.code = a.code and a1.deleted = 0) and
      deleted_date = (select max(a1.deleted_date) from analyzes a1 where a1.code = a.code);
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e53674/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE analyzes ( ID int, code varchar(10), deleted bit, deleted_Date date) ;

INSERT INTO analyzes (ID, code, deleted, deleted_Date)
SELECT 1, '01.00.002', 1, '2018-01-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '01.00.002', 1, '2018-02-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 15, '01.00.002', 1, '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '01.00.005', 1, '2018-01-21' UNION ALL
SELECT 17, '01.00.005', 1, '2018-01-10' UNION ALL
SELECT 16, '01.00.006', 0, null UNION ALL
SELECT 18, '01.00.007', 1, '2018-01-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 19, '01.00.007', 0, null UNION ALL
SELECT 42, '01.00.007', 1, '2018-01-25'
;
```

**Main Query**:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM analyzes a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t1.code, max(t1.deleted_date) AS maxDel
  FROM analyzes t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN analyzes t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
    AND t2.deleted = 0
  WHERE t2.id IS NULL
  GROUP BY t1.code
) s1 ON a.code = s1.code and a.Deleted_Date = s1.maxDel
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e53674/1/0)**:

```
| ID |      code | deleted | deleted_Date |
|----|-----------|---------|--------------|
| 15 | 01.00.002 |    true |   2018-03-01 |
|  3 | 01.00.005 |    true |   2018-01-21 |
```

This query first uses a sub-select to get the `code` and max `deleted_date` from your dataset. It uses a `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL` pattern to eliminate the related `code`s that have at least one record that isn't `deleted`. This will scale very well with a large dataset. Then the outer query just `INNER JOIN`s back to the inner query on the `code` and the calculated max `deleted_date`.